# Incorporating multiple software names and e.g., within in-text citation

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm hoping someone can help me with this in-text citation issue I can't seem to figure out.  I am using natbib and have an in-text citation that should look something like this: (e.g., PSD; Horner, 1990; Polluck, 2001; TSD; Green, 2003).  I assume the latex syntax should be something like this: citep/[e.g.,][][PSD;][]{Horner... but this initial syntax is not working correctly and I'm not sure how to incorporate the other software name.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!